# Highcharts - Reset zoom in synchronised charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using the *syncExtremes* function to synchronise multiple charts (and their zooms) as implemented in the example below:

https://jsfiddle.net/pz2bak0u

However I've come across two issues I can't seem to find my way around. The first one is that if you zoom multiple times in different charts without reseting and then click on one of the *Reset zoom* buttons, the other Reset zoom buttons hang around (and I would like them to disappear as they don't have any functionality when clicked).

I then modified the fiddle to allow *xy* zooming:

https://jsfiddle.net/47dz68Lt

If you zoom in on the first chart, then the second, and then the third, and try unzooming the first chart, the other two stay halfway zoomed.

I've tried
`chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(null, null);` 
but haven't had any luck.

Is it even posible to reset all xy zooming in all charts at the same time as in the x zooming example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you reset only x-axes extremes, with `xy` zoom type, you need to also reset y-axes extremes:

```
var H = Highcharts;

H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'zoomOut', function(proceed) {

    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    H.charts.forEach(function(chart) {
        if (chart !== this) {
            chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(null, null, undefined, false);
        }
    }, this);
});
```

To control the display of the `resetZoomButton`, you can wrap `showResetZoom` method, for example:

```
H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'showResetZoom', function(proceed) {
    var visibleBtn = false;

    H.charts.forEach(function(chart) {
        if (chart.resetZoomButton) {
            visibleBtn = true;
        }
    });

    if (!visibleBtn) {
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bg7L1nev/

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts